How to detect if running under ValveSoftware's Proton in C++
I'm looking for ways to detect if my app is running under ValveSoftware's Proton. There are ways of getting the Wine version proton uses with the wine_get_version dll export. But there seem to be workarounds within proton that make this method unreliable.
Is there any de-facto way similar to wine_get_version for proton in order to reliably detect it's use?

I'd hope that there's no easy way to detect that, because once software starts detecting emulation and compatibility layers or virtualization and whatnot and start acting on that knowledge, then emulation and virtualization etc just gets harder and won't produce the expected results. Hopefully, emulation will just work flawlessly and the software running in that environment should be oblivious to that fact (otherwise it's not really full emulation/virtualization/etc, is it?).

Is there a particular reason why you need to do that? In many situations, you want to do feature (or maybe bug detection) instead of environment detection.

@t.niese I'm looking into different ways to prevent and/or discourage users from running the application under Linux.

@Boyfinn But wouldn't a "Supported Plattform" information be sufficient? Purely personal and subjective opinion: I as much as I can try to get away from windows, because it gets more and more bloated, but I have a bunch of windows applications that I love and paid for, and I would love to support them also in future, so I'm always happy if I can get them running under Linux, so that I don't need to run them in kvm/vm or reboot, and I'm fully aware that those might not run perfectly fine. But if I'm prevented from using it even if it might work, I likely look for alternatives.

I fully understand it from a crash/bug-reporting standpoint, but at that point (from the stack trace) it should be detectable, and showing "We don't support ..., please report the problem to, ..." should be possible.

@t.niese I understant, I personally am running Mint as my daily driver. I'm doing this for research.

"I'm looking into different ways to prevent and/or discourage users from running the application under Linux" ... but ... Why?

I don't know the answer, but there are two things I would look into. One would be similar to what you have: check for additional proton-specific "private" functions that are not exposed and check for their existence. The other idea would be checking if one (or more) Windows-specific dlls where proton uses a replacement are properly signed (assuming proton does not mock that). But you always need to assume that those methods will only work for the version you found and older ones.
